# Using jQuery to remove html elements from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel-5.1

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.notification .tools .remove').on('click', function () {
            alert('hola');
            $(this).parentsUntil('.notification').remove();
        });
    });


</script>

<div id="notification-list" class="notification-chain" style="display:none">

    @foreach ($notifications as $notification)

    <div class="notification" style="width:300px">

        <div class="tools">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="notification-messages">

            <div class="message-wrapper">

                <div class="heading">{{ $notification->name }}</div>
                <div class="description">{{ 'User ' .$notification->points_to. ' ' .$notification->content }}</div>
                <div class="date pull-left">{{ $notification->created_at }}</div>

            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

        </div>

    </div>

    @endforeach

</div>
```

Hello readers,

Above is currently what I'm working with. It displays a drop-down to hold all notifications a user has received and I currently have an **x** in the top corner of each "notification" div.

However none of the above jQuery seems to be running. The alert won't display and I get nothing in the console.

Please feel free to ridicule me and tell me what stupid thing I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks.

---

I appreciate all the help guys.

Here are some laravel.io files with some wider context:

**The full html:**
http://laravel.io/bin/Nk4xP

**js for the dropdown:**
http://laravel.io/bin/9vn1O#

Comment: you're missing a class from the `parentsUntil('.notification')`

Comment: @LukeVincent Just fyi, you can click on the source tab in Chrome's F12 to put in breakpoints and add watches to get a better idea of what's going on in your javascript/jquery.

Comment: @gaynorvador that's really useful I didn't know you could put breakpoints in with chrome. From the looks of things it's never even making it past the selector.

Comment: @PauloPedroso - are you referring to the template tags? `{{ }}` - that's the syntax for Laravel's blade templating engine too.

Comment: @Kryten Yes, after double checking I noticed it. And I removed my useless comment. :-) But I have posted my test below, removing the Laravel stuff the javascript works. See the link to the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some debugging tips:

Think about all the things that might be going wrong, then start ruling them out. For example:

1. Maybe jQuery is not loaded at all.
2. Maybe the selector for the event handler is incorrect and jQuery can't find an element to attach the event handler to.
3. Maybe the code in your `$(document).ready()` function is not executing, and the event handler is never set up.

Using a combination of changes to your code and the browser console, you can rule these three things out:

Is jQuery loaded? Open the console & type `$` - if it says `undefined`, then that's your problem.

Is the selector for the element incorrect? Open the console and type `$('.notification .tools .remove')`. If you get an empty array, then that's your problem. As an added bonus, Chrome (and probably other browsers) will highlight the selected element if you mouse over it - this is useful in case you're selecting a different element than you expected.

Is the `$(document).ready()` code executing? Stick a different `alert` in there at the top of the function & see if it fires when you reload the page.

It's important to tackle issues like these one at a time - what happens if you change two or more things at once, and the problem goes away (or a new problem arises)? You won't know which one solved or caused the problem!

Comment: This is a stellar response thank you. I've done a couple of things since posting. Firstly removing the "notification" div from the drop-down and placing it elsewhere on the page has proven it works outside.

It seems to break only while it is within the drop-down. I've also done as you've said and typed the selector into the console. An array is populated with the expected number of elements however only the element outside of the dropdown are highlighted when I hover over them.

Comment: Interesting... is it possible that jQuery doesn't attach an event handler to an element with `display: none`? I've never heard of this behaviour... time to experiment a little :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work in the fiddle below.
I removed the display:none (so I can see the div) and the non html characters. Try looking at the browser console (F12 in linux and windows computers) and see if there are errors. Javascript errors will prevent further code to run.

Also I put a text within the a href tag

```
<a href="javascript:void()" class="remove">remove</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m9rktusb/

Answer (score 0):

As notification is a class for the div, there should be a dot in front of the class as a selector like this:

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.notification').remove();
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Sorry that was a silly typo. I've made the alteration, but to no surprise it hasn't solved the problem as the alert isn't firing so it's failing before this point.

Answer (score 0):

Luke can you please show us the final HTML?
the code is running perfectly, so the issue should be somewhere else.
https://jsfiddle.net/z7958hx7/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.notification .tools .remove').on('click', function() {
        alert('hola');
        $(this).parentsUntil('.notification').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I've added the full html to the laravel.io pastebin and provided links

Comment: @LukeVincent sorry for the late reply. I was talking about the full html out put (the rendered html generated by blade) :). 
I could be wrong, but I'm thinking that the issue could something that is preventing the page to finish loading.
Luke could you please try this solution? 
http://laravel.io/bin/PXJ5z
If that doesn't work, you probably have a js error else where :/
(sorry for my english O:) )